# NextJS - @microsoft/signalr TS package fails when building project using pnpm

Tags: next.js, signalr, pnpm

I am working with NextJs, Typescript and @microsoft/signalr.

I built my project using "pnpm build" command, but I get below error.
[image]

This is my package.json file

```
     "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next build && next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
         "@ant-design/icons": "^5.1.4",
         "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
         "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
         "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.7",
         "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
         "antd": "^5.6.4",
         "axios": "^1.4.0",
         "eslint": "8.39.0",
         "eslint-config-next": "13.4.0",
         "framer-motion": "^10.12.18",
         "immer": "^10.0.2",
         "js-convert-case": "^4.2.0",
         "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
         "lodash": "^4.17.21",
         "next": "13.4.0",
         "next-i18next": "^13.3.0",
         "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.1.0",
         "polylabel": "^1.1.0",
         "qs": "^6.11.2",
         "react": "18.2.0",
         "react-dom": "18.2.0",
         "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
         "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
         "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
         "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
         "three": "^0.153.0",
         "uuid": "^9.0.0"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
     "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.3",
     "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
     "@types/node": "^20.3.3",
     "@types/polylabel": "^1.1.0",
     "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
     "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
     "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/three": "^0.152.1",
     "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
     "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
   }
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.